# Access <object> data with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, object, plaintext

I have an `<object>` tag like this:

```
<object id="text" data="file.txt"></object>
```

And I can get the element like this:

```
var text = document.getElementById("text");
```

Now, how do I get the content of the text file?

The purpose of this is to:

1. avoid having to make an XMLHttpRequest;
2. avoid having text data in the form of a constant in code;
3. keep a simple plaintext file in it's original form, without JSON or special formatting, to be accessed by code and become a string variable.

In the same fashion you can have an `<img>` or `<audio>` tag in the document and then access the image / sound, just for text files.

PS: I'm almost positive the `<object>` tag is not the ideal tag for this. This is just as far as I came trying to accomplish what I need.

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly: load data from a file into your web page?

Comment: More precisely, load a .txt file which is sibling to my .html and .js file into a JS variable.

Comment: Note that even with the file being added to an object in this fashion, the browser is still going to make a request to the server to get it, so whilst you're avoiding making an explicit request yourself, the browser will still be doing so.

Comment: Yes, no problem about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load your text file within a hidden iframe and access the contents within that:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function gettext() {
                alert(document.getElementById('ifr').contentDocument.body.innerText);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <iframe id="ifr" style="display:none" src="test.txt" onload="gettext()"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's precisely what I wanted! And it works with the `<object>` tag, too! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I normally prefer AJAX for something like this.  Could you do something like this?

```
var textContent = '';
var textRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
textRequest.open('GET','file.txt');

textRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (textRquest.readystate == 4 && textRequest.status == 200) {
        textContent = textRequest.responseText   
    }
}

textRequest.send();
```

Is there a reason you *have* to use an object element?

Comment: It doesn't really have to be an object element. All I need is to embed some plain text to my document (preferably from a separate file) so I can read it with JavaScript. I wanted it to be clean and simple and that's why I avoided requests as my first option. Sorry, I should have mentioned that before. Thanks.